# PHP PDO::bindParam() data types.. how does it work?

Tags: php, types, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm wondering what the declaration of the data type in [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) (or [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)) is used for...

I mean, I thought that if I define an integer argument (`PDO::PARAM_INT`), the argument must be converted to an integer, something like

```
$delete->bindParam(1, $kill, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// should work like
$delete->bindParam(1, (int)$kill);
```

or at least throw an error if the argument is not of the declared type. But this is not the case.

Googling around, I found that in the php.net archive:

> Hi all,
>
> I am currently working on PDO. Exactly
>   on the bindParam() function. The third
>   parameter data_type seems to be here
>   to force the type of the value ? But
>   when I try :
>
> ```
> $sql = "INSERT INTO produit (idproduit, nom, marque) VALUES (NULL, :nom, :marque)";
> $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
> $nom = 'Testarossa'; $marque = 'Ferrari' ;
> $stmt->BindValue(':marque',$marque) ;
> $stmt->BindParam(':nom',$nom,PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
>
> $stmt->execute(); $nom = '250 GTO' ;
> $stmt->execute(); ?>
> ```
>
> I was expecting to have either a PHP
>   error or an interger in my database.
>   But in my DB I have :
>
> 22 Testarossa Ferrari 23 250 GTO
>   Ferrari
>
> It mean that it didn't change if I
>   have the third parameter or not. Or
>   perhaps I miss something. Can someone
>   tole me more ? Or just can someone
>   told me where I can find information
>   about it.
>
> Regards,
>
> Cyruss

That is exactly my situation. Where are my thoughts going wrong?

Comment: "I was expecting to have either a PHP error or an interger in my database." me too

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It can be used for things like making sure PDO is doing the proper escaping for in-lining values (for drivers that don't support proper bound parameters) and improving network efficiency by making sure numbers are binary packed appropriately (given protocol support).

It looks like in base PDO, it doesn't do much.

```
if (PDO_PARAM_TYPE(param->param_type) == PDO_PARAM_STR && param->max_value_len <= 0 && !Z_ISNULL_P(parameter)) {
    if (!try_convert_to_string(parameter)) {
        return 0;
    }
} else if (PDO_PARAM_TYPE(param->param_type) == PDO_PARAM_INT && (Z_TYPE_P(parameter) == IS_FALSE || Z_TYPE_P(parameter) == IS_TRUE)) {
    convert_to_long(parameter);
} else if (PDO_PARAM_TYPE(param->param_type) == PDO_PARAM_BOOL && Z_TYPE_P(parameter) == IS_LONG) {
    convert_to_boolean(parameter);
}
```

So, if you say it is a string (or if you say nothing at all as that is the default) and your data's type is something other than a NULL then it will convert it into a string.

If you say it's an int but you bind a bool then it will convert it to an integer.

If you say it's a bool but you bind a number then it will convert it to a true boolean.

When emulation mode is turned on, the type hint is used to determine how to inject it into the SQL string.

Additionally, PDO provides this information to the database drivers, which can then be used to bind the data most optimally or correctly, depending on the particular DB's requirements.

Answer (score 23):

So I decided to dive into the PHP source code and this is what I found.

`static int really_register_bound_param` in ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c on line 329 of version 8.3.0

```
if (PDO_PARAM_TYPE(param->param_type) == PDO_PARAM_STR && param->max_value_len <= 0 && !Z_ISNULL_P(parameter)) {
    if (!try_convert_to_string(parameter)) {
        return 0;
    }
} else if (PDO_PARAM_TYPE(param->param_type) == PDO_PARAM_INT && (Z_TYPE_P(parameter) == IS_FALSE || Z_TYPE_P(parameter) == IS_TRUE)) {
    convert_to_long(parameter);
} else if (PDO_PARAM_TYPE(param->param_type) == PDO_PARAM_BOOL && Z_TYPE_P(parameter) == IS_LONG) {
    convert_to_boolean(parameter);
}
```

These are the conversions PDO does during binding.

- PDO::PARAM_STR converts whatever you give it to a string except null.
- PDO::PARAM_INT converts bools into integers
- PDO::PARAM_BOOL converts longs into bools

That's it.  Nothing else is converted.  PDO uses the PARAM flags to format SQL not to cast data types.

Answer (score 6):

There's at least one effect PDO::PARAM_INT has on **INSERT** queries: boolean values are converted to 0 or 1. Like in

```
$i = true;
$stmt->bindParam(':i', $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

pdo_stmt.c:

```
else if (PDO_PARAM_TYPE(param->param_type) == PDO_PARAM_INT && Z_TYPE_P(param->parameter) == IS_BOOL) {
        convert_to_long(param->parameter);
}
```

Comment: Oh.. im wondering if this effect really is usefull.. what about other data_typeS? string, etc?

Comment: I haven't found reliable documentation for these features. Therefore I could go through all the code in /ext/pdo* ...or simply not rely on that parameter for INSERT, UPDATE... queries.

Comment: Ok, i'll give a try on the SELECT queries to see if the 'problem' affet them too...
Sad, anyway, that the data_type declaration would be usefull even for the sanitization/flow-control in the INSERT queries.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same thing with BindValue and got the same result so the behavior you are seeing is not limited to bindParam.

```
$stmt->BindValue(':marque', $marque) ;
$stmt->BindValue(':nom', $nom, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;

$stmt->execute();
$nom = '250 GTO';
$stmt->BindValue(':nom', $nom, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
$stmt->execute();
```