# PHP: 'or' statement on instruction fail: how to throw a new exception?

Tags: php, exception, logical-operators

Everyone here should know the 'or' statemens, usually glued to an die() command:

```
$foo = bar() or die('Error: bar function return false.');
```

The most of the times we see something like:

```
mysql_query('SELECT ...') or die('Error in during the query');
```

However, i cant understand how exactly that 'or' statement works.

I would like to throw a new exception instead of die(), but:

```
try{
    $foo = bar() or throw new Exception('We have a problem here');
```

Doesnt work, and neither

```
$foo = bar() or function(){ throw new Exception('We have a problem here'); }
```

The only way i found to do that is this horrible thought:

```
function ThrowMe($mess, $code){
    throw new Exception($mess, $code);
}
try{
    $foo = bar() or ThrowMe('We have a problem in here', 666);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But there is a way to throw a new exception directly after the 'or' statement?

Or this kind of structure is mandatory (i dont liek the ThrowMe function at all):

```
try{
    $foo = bar();
    if(!$foo){
        throw new Exception('We have a problem in here');
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Edit**: what i want is really to avoid the use of an if() check every potential dangerous operation i do, for example:

```
#The echo $e->getMessage(); is just an example, in real life this have no sense!
try{
    $foo = bar();
    if(!$foo){
        throw new Exception('Problems with bar()');
    }
    $aa = bb($foo);
    if(!$aa){
        throw new Exception('Problems with bb()');
    }
    //...and so on!
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

#But i relly prefer to use something like:

try{
    $foo = bar() or throw new Exception('Problems with bar()');
    $aa = bb($foo) or throw new Exception('Problems with bb()');
    //...and so on!
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

#Actually, the only way i figured out is:

try{
    $foo = bar() or throw new ThrowMe('Problems with bar()', 1);
    $aa = bb($foo) or throw new ThrowMe('Problems with bb()', 2);
    //...and so on!
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

#But i'll love to thro the exception directly instead of trick it with ThrowMe function.
```

Comment: Did you mean `!$foo` in your last block of code?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`or` is just a [logical operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), and it's analogous to `||`.

The common trick of

```
mysql_query() or die();
```

could just as well be written

```
mysql_query() || die();
```

What happens here is the "logical or" operator (whichever you choose) is trying to determine if either operand evaluates to TRUE. This means the operands must be expressions that can be cast as a boolean.

So, the reason

```
bar() or throw new Exception();
```

is illegal, is because

```
(boolean)throw new Exception();
```

is also illegal. In essence, the process of throwing an exception doesn't generate a return value for the operator to check.

But calling a function *does* generate a return value for the operator to check (no explicit return value will result int the function returning `NULL` which casts as `FALSE`) which is why it works for you when you wrap exception throwing in a function.

Comment: `or` is not analogous to `||`.  The former has lower precedence than assignment and comparison.  The latter has higher.  This is a very important distinction because `$f = one() or two()` works very differently from `$f = one() || two()`.  http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Yes it is.  "Analogous" doesn't mean "identical".  That being said, your clarification is welcome :D

Comment: The error the bad syntax invokes is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_THROW"

Answer (score 3):

I've simply defined the function `toss` for this.

```php
function toss(Exception $exception): void
{
    throw $exception;
}
```

Because the file/line/stack information is captured when the exception is *constructed* (`new`) not thrown (`throw`) this doesn't interfere with the call stack.

So you can just do this.

```php
something() or toss(new Exception('something failed'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't `bar()` and `bb()` throw the exceptions? In PHP Exceptions bubble up, so there's no need to throw the exception in the function/method where you call `bar()`/`bb()`. These exceptions may be thrown by `bar()`/`bb()`. In case you want to throw another exception, you can simply do:

```
function foo() {
    try {
        $bar = bar();
    } catch (BarException) {
        throw new FooException;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes man, youre right, but what about, for example, the database functions? mysql_query()/pg_query()? For these i must use or the if() check, or the ThrowMe horrible function.. i just want to know if is possible doing id direclty without ThrowMe()

Comment: @DaNieL: You could use PDO for DB access which can throw exceptions itself.

Comment: Well, it's not possible. I've tried it myself some time ago and no chance. PHP is a useful tool, but it also has one of the most stupid parsers and interpreters in the world.

Comment: Anyway, if you strive to abstract your application, you shouldn't have that many calls to `mysql_query()` or whatever. You should build your own layer of utilities on top of PHP so that you can mask all its idiosyncrasies.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, tryed PDO a lot and i dont ahve a good consideration of it, this is an example of the motivation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833510/php-pdobindparam-data-types-how-does-it-work 
Im building up my 'lite, small and fast' PDO interpretation ;)
@lonut: so we have another thing to add in the php6 whishlist?

Comment: @DaNieL, there would be lots of things for the PHP6 wish list, but I don't actually see the internals considering that many of them. At this time on the internals mailing list is discussed an RFC which proposes the replacement of errors with exceptions in built-in functions/classes. And it's very unlikely that it will get accepted.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I found that can replace "or die()" everywhere is to wrap the throw with a anonymous function that gets called immediately by call_user_func:

```
call_user_func(function(){
    throw new Exception("ERROR");
});
```

You can see that it works by executing this on a dummy script:

```
false or call_user_func(function(){throw new Exception("ERROR");});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use something like the last structure, although there's really no point in using exceptions for that:

```
$foo = bar();
if(!$foo){
    echo 'We have a problem in here';
}
```

Per comment - I don't think you can do that in a single line (i.e. without the `if(!$foo)` check), and I agree that the exception throwing method is pretty horrible. Personally, I prefer the explicitness of:

```
$foo = bar();
if(!$foo){
    throw new Exception('We have a problem in here');
}
```

but that's a personal preference. If you want the single-line thing, I think you'll have to go with your exception-throwing function option.

I guess this limitation is probably down to PHP's dynamic-typing stuff, it can cast the results of a function call to a conditional, but not the results of a `throw`.

Comment: No, i dont want to. The echo is just for example, in real life never echo the error message or code but handle them differently.

What i want is exactly avoiding the if(!$foo) check every time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single-line solution without the extra function:

```
if (!($foo = bar())) throw new Exception('We have a problem here');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a custom exception class and use it's static constructor method instead of `throw new Exception()` construction.

Exception class:

```
class CustomException extends Exception {
  static public function doThrow($message = "", $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
    throw new Exception($message, $code, $previous);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
try {

  $foo = bar() or CustomException::doThrow('Problems with bar()');
  $aa = bb($foo) or CustomException::doThrow('Problems with bb()');

} catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

> **Note**
>
> If you are using PHP 7 and higher - you can rename static method `doThrow()` to simply `throw()`, since in PHP 7 and higher it's allowed to use reserved keywords as method names.