# PHP rename() doesn't throws exception on error

Tags: php, exception

I'm working with a php application, and there is a line that moves a file. I enclosed the method within a try...catch block so, if a error is thrown, can manage a rollback system. But the exception is never catched, so, renames throws any kind of exception? Do I need to try with another method?

Thanks

Code above:

```
try{
   if(rename($archivo_salida, $ruta_archivos)){
    //anything;
   }

}catch (Exception $e)
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Normal" PHP functions don't throw exceptions.

Change your code to simulate an exception:

```
try {
   if (rename($archivo_salida, $ruta_archivos)) {
      //anything;
   } else {
      throw new Exception('Can not rename file'.$archivo_salida);
   }
} catch (Exception $e) {
   //do something, such as
   echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: There could be a automatic Error to Exception transformer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10919969/22470

Answer (score 4):

`rename()` only ever returns true/false - there is no thrown exception.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 3):

It returns `FALSE` on failure. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

If you really need an exception to be thrown when the rename fails, you can do this:

```
if (rename($archivo_salida, $ruta_archivos)) {
    // anything;
} else {
    throw new Exception("Rename failed.");
}
```

Now, you can wrap this around a `try {} catch {}` block where ever you are invoking this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the same approach as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364340/563049

Create a custom exception class and use it's static constructor method with `or` operator after `rename()`.

Exception class:

```
class CustomException extends Exception {
  static public function doThrow($message = "", $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
    throw new Exception($message, $code, $previous);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
try {

  rename($archivo_salida, $ruta_archivos) or CustomException::doThrow('Renaming failed.');

} catch (Exception $e){
  //do something
}
```

> **Note**
>
> If you are using PHP 7 and higher - you can rename static method `doThrow()` to simply `throw()`, since in PHP 7 and higher it's allowed to use reserved keywords as method names.