# How can I reliably identify a specific error in PHP?

Tags: php, exception

Because of PHP's `unlink()` not supporting exceptions natively, I'm making a wrapper function for it. It should throw a `FileNotFoundException` if, well, the given file could not be deleted because it doesn't exist.

For this, I need to determine whether the error thrown by `unlink()` was caused by a missing file or something else.

This is my test version for a custom delete function:

```
public function deleteFile($path){
    set_error_handler(function($errLevel, $errString){
        debug($errLevel);
        debug($errString);
    });
    unlink($path);
    restore_error_handler();
}
```

For `$errLevel` and `$errString` I get *2* (E_WARNING) and *unlink(/tmp/fooNonExisting): No such file or directory*

A rather bold approach would be like this:

```
if( strpos($errString, 'No such file or directory') !== false ) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
};
```

Question 1: How much can I rely on the error string being the same across different PHP versions? Question 2: Is there a much better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify the code:

```php
public function deleteFile($path){

    if (!file_exists($path) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }else{
        unlink($path);
    }

    if (file_exists($path) {
        throw new FileNotDeleted();
    }
}
```

Then you don't have to catch the `$errstr` and do complicated error catching. And it will work down to PHP 4 when exceptions were introduced.

Comment: Yes, good solution. But this will bury all other types of problems, too, like wrong file permissions. I'd rather only convert "file not found" into an exception.

Comment: I modified your solution (review pending), with `unlink()` in an `else` block we can get rid of the bad `@` part. I'll probably use this technique, but let's wait what other answers are coming about the initial error handling/identification issue.

Comment: Choosing this answer as correct, even though it does not teach me lots of details about PHP error handlers. But it points in a *simple* direction, which I was also asking for.

Comment: For PHP error "magic" have a look at http://php.net/manual/function.error-get-last.php and http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php

Answer (score 1):

While reading trough my old [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607539/is-there-any-native-php-function-which-throws-an-built-in-exception) I came across the [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/class.errorexception.php), combined with `set_error_handler()` this would be a automatic ***Error to Exception transformer*** for all native PHP errors:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

/* Trigger exception */
unlink('Does not exitsts');
```

Can anybody prof this?

Comment: It won't work for every error. Beside parser-time and startup errors, some other runtime errors, as fatal errors, are not catch by any error handler.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it(i.e. your code) should be portable enough as it is...
As regards a better way to achieve the same thing, i would do things differently (although the code is simple, it's also more readable...so bear with me)

```
function deleteFile($file_path){
    if(!is_file($file_path)){
        throw new Exception("The path does not seem to point to a valid file");
    }
    if(!file_exists($file_path)){
        throw new Exception("File not found!");
    }
    if(unlink($file_path)){
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("File deletion failed!");
    }
}
```

Of course you can always compress and improve on the code...hop this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen php error messages change quite a bit over the years. Maybe, try to detect a change in the last error over a very granular piece of code, and then result to string parsing in a very loose manor.

```
$lastErr = error_get_last();
unlink($file);
if ($lastErr !== error_get_last()) {
    // do something
    //maybe string parsing and/or testing with file_exists, is_writable etc...
}
```