# PHP old-school function "or" with exception

Tags: php, function, exception, boolean, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: 'or' statement on instruction fail: how to throw a new exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211237/php-or-statement-on-instruction-fail-how-to-throw-a-new-exception)

In PHP, especially popular amongst the newbies in various MySQL connection tutorials, you've always been able to do something like this...

```
<?php
foo() or die('foo() failed!');
?>
```

However if I try something like this it fails...

```
<?php
foo() or throw new Exception('AHH!');
?>
```

Like so...

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'throw' (T_THROW) in..."

Anybody know how to do something similar to this?  Would I have to set a variable after the "or"?

Comment: You could define a `throwException()` function that simply throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the responses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do it the less "clever" way:

```
if(!foo()) {
    throw new Exception('AHH!');
}
```

In case you're wondering why `or throw new Exception()` doesn't work, it's because you're relying on the [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of the [`or` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction): If the first argument is true, then there's no need to evaluate the second to determine if one of them is true (since you already know that *at least* one of them is true).

You can't do this with `throw` since it's an expression that doesn't return a boolean value (or any value at all), so `or`ing doesn't make any sense.

If you **really** want to do this, the deleted answer by @emie should work (make a function that just throws an exception), since even a function with no return value is valid in a boolean statement, but it seems like a bad idea to create a function like that just so you can do clever things with boolean statements.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work because `throw`, just like `echo`, `include`, etc. is a language construct rather than a function :)

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid the IF statement.  So useful, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

The similar question has been asked before.

[PHP: 'or' statement on instruction fail: how to throw a new exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211237/php-or-statement-on-instruction-fail-how-to-throw-a-new-exception)

> the reason
>
> ```
> bar() or throw new Exception();
> ```
>
> is illegal, is because
>
> ```
> (boolean)throw new Exception();
> ```
>
> is also illegal. In essence, the process of throwing an exception
>   doesn't generate a return value for the operator to check.