# How to bind SQL variables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, binding

I want to bind variables instead of just building SQL strings.
Anyway to do this in Php?

Either MySQL or PostgreSQL answers would help.

Thanks

Comment: Binding records from a table to objects in your application or "binding" variables in PHP to variables in SQL?

Comment: "binding" variables in PHP to variables in SQL :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's e.g. [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo).
An introduction to pdo and prepared statements (including bound parameters) is located at http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: carefull with PDO::bindParam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833510/php-pdobindparam-data-types-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 4):

You should read on the MySQL Improved Extension (MySQLi) at http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php , and on prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

For **Postgres** specifically - [`pg_query_params`](http://www.php.net/pg_query_params) (and [`pg_send_query_params`](http://www.php.net/pg_send_query_params)) is the most primitive form of binding but still very useful.

And then there's PDO but the others already mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of flavors.  I believe the more savvy individuals here will push for you to use PDO prepared statements.  There is also a sprintf() version.

### PDO

An answer has already been discussed on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements).

### SPRINTF

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %d AND field = %s',
               $id,
               mysql_real_escape_string($value));
```

Comment: how sprintf is a bind variables replacemet? there are no DB checks on the variables content. This is as not safe as the plain text stuff

Comment: The sprintf version is vulnerable to sql injection and should not be used.