# Mysql Select Where Not Exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables:

table name:: student

```
studentid     studentname
1001          Charlie Sheen
1002          John Cryer
```

table name:: studentpayment1

```
paymentid  studentid    fee_month  fee_year  totalamount
  1234          1001     February    2012        $500
  4321          1002     January     2012       $1500
```

table name:: studentpayment2

```
 id          pid        fee_type        fee_amount
 1          1234        Monthly Fee           $500
 2          4321        Exam Fee             $1500
```

Now, I am trying to find out the name of the students who hasn't paid the "Monthly Fee" for the month of February - year 2012.

I tried this following code but it doesn't generate the correct information.

```
$year="2012"; $month="February"; $fee_type="Monthly Fee";


SELECT DISTINCT studentid,
                studentname
FROM   student
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT   *
                   FROM     studentpayment1
                     JOIN   studentpayment2
                     ON     studentpayment1.paymentid = studentpayment2.pid
                   WHERE    fee_month = '$month'
                     AND    fee_type = '$fee_type'
                     AND    fee_year = '$year'
                     AND    student.studentid = studentpayment1.studentid)
LIMIT  $perPage
```

How do I fix this query?

Comment: @black_belt Try this query: `SELECT studentname  FROM studentname, studentpayment1, studentpayment2 WHERE student.studentid = studentpayment1.studentid AND pid = paymentid AND fee_type != "Monthly Fee" AND fee_year = "2012" AND fee_month ="February"`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the students who paid nothing ever, nothing in February 2012, or no Monthly fees in Feb, 2012

```
SELECT * FROM student s 
   LEFT JOIN studentpayment1 sp1 
      ON s.studentid = sp1.studentid 
        AND ((sp1.fee_month = 'February' AND sp1.fee_year = '2012') OR sp1.fee_month is null)
   LEFT JOIN studentpayment2 sp2 
      ON sp1.paymentid = sp2.pid AND ( sp2.fee_type  = 'Monthly Fee' OR  sp2.fee_type is null)
   WHERE sp1.fee_month is null or sp2.fee_type is null
```

good luck

BTW here is some good schema advice: change all the primary keys on the tab to just 'id' and be consistant with you naming of foriegn keys:  the primay key to the student table should be just 'id' in the studentpayment1 table it should have a column called student_id.  The studentpayment2 table should have a column pointing to the studentpayment1 called studentpayment1_id not 'pid'.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should not be within the single quotes:

```
"WHERE    fee_month = '".$month."' "
```

Even better would be to bind your variables.

Discussion on binding here: [How to bind SQL variables in Php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860130/how-to-bind-sql-variables-in-php)

Comment: The OP may be in need of an example of binding variables.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running this query in real time, but this should help you out.

```
select distinct studentid from student where studentid NOT EXISTS (select studentid from studentpayment1 where  fee_month = '$month'
                     AND    fee_type = '$fee_type'
                     AND    fee_year = '$year')
```

or

```
select distinct studentid from student where NOT EXISTS (select studentid from studentpayment1 where  fee_month = '$month'
                     AND    fee_type = '$fee_type'
                     AND    fee_year = '$year')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your subquery is correct (I haven't look at it) query bellow should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT studentid,studentname FROM student WHERE
studentid NOT IN (SELECT studentid FROM studentpayment1 JOIN studentpayment2 ON studentpayment1.paymentid=studentpayment2.pid WHERE 
fee_month='$month' AND fee_type='$fee_type' AND fee_year='$year' AND student.studentid=studentpayment1.studentid ) LIMIT $perPage
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried all the solutions posted here, but none of them worked. But after working on it 12 hours straight I figured out that my db query was okay I had some problems with some codes above the mysql query. I am sorry for creating this post. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will do the thing:

```
$year="2012"; $month="February"; $fee_type="Monthly Fee";

$students_with_debt = "SELECT name FROM student WHERE studentid NOT IN (SELECT studentid FROM studentpayment1 p1 INNER JOIN studentpayment2 p2 ON p1.paymentid = p2.pid WHERE fee_month = '$month' AND p1.fee_year = '$year' AND p2.fee_type = '$fee_type');"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using LEFT JOINs instead:

```
SELECT student.studentid, student.studentname FROM student
LEFT JOIN studentpayment1 ON studentpayment1.studentid = student.studentid
  AND studentpayment1.fee_month = ?
  AND studentpayment1.fee_year  = ?
LEFT JOIN studentpayment2 ON studentpayment2.pid = studentpayment1.paymentid
  AND studentpayment2.fee_type = ?
WHERE studentpayment2.id IS NULL
```

Make sure to put indexes on fee_month, fee_year, and fee_type, and replace all ? with your variables.

Comment: The OP might appreciate an explanation of why this approach works where the original failed.  And what the benefits/drawback of adding indexes are.