# inserting/reading blob data from php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, upload, blob

I am using the following scripts to test inserting and then reading blob data.

insertion script:

```
include('session.php');

$provider      =$_POST['provider_id'];
$trd_period    =$_POST['trading_period_month'];
$pdf_statement =stream_get_contents(fopen($_FILES['pdf_statement']['tmp_name'], 'rb'));
$pdf_statement_clean=addslashes($pdf_statement);


$insert="update rd_provider_statement
         set pdf_statement='".$pdf_statement_clean."', creation_user_id='SCO'
         where  provider_id='".$provider."' and trading_period_month='".$trd_period."'";

mysql_query($insert);
mysql_query("COMMIT"); 

echo mysql_error();
```

Download Script:

```
include('session.php');

//Gather Post Variables
$TP_Month  =$_POST["trading_period_month"];
$provider =$_POST["provider_id"];
$TP_format =substr($TP_Month, 0, 7);

//Download Statement

$sql_qry="select *
          from   rd_provider_statement
          where  provider='".$provider."' and trading_period_month='".$TP_Month."'";
$sql_err_no=sql_select($sql_qry,$sql_res,$sql_row_count,$sql_err,$sql_uerr);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res);
$bytes =stripslashes($row['pdf_statement']);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$provider.'statement'.$TP_format.'"');
print $bytes;
```

However, when the file is downloaded it cannot open on the grounds that it is not a supported format. I use the basis of the script on another page to download blob data from the database however the insertion into the database here is done by a mysql procedure and not PHP. I think it is my insertion script that is causing the problem.

Comment: storing files in database is not a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: So if you're on hosting and there's no other way to store/retrieve files on a filesystem how would one like, store and retrieve files? Sometimes they've got those strict PHP/MySQL deals or they cap/filter your file uploads or something.

Answer (score 1):

try using `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of  `addslashes()`. it might fix you problem.

For debugging, you might calculate the `md5()` of the string before inserting into DB and then after retrieving it. I bet you're going to get different hashes, meaning you're not inserting it correctly and your binary data gets corrupted when inserted into the DB.

Side notes:

- don't use inserts like that, use binding - [How to bind SQL variables in Php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860130/how-to-bind-sql-variables-in-php)
- check for errors and STOP, dont simply echo them(i hope you're doing this in your production code)

Comment: I originally had mysql_real_escape_string() but changed to slashes after I could not get to work. md5 check returned completely different hashes. I have no idea why though. The production code stops on error and rollsback any changes... as this is only for testing I like to keep the code as minimal as possible until it is fulyl working

Comment: the column in the DB is BLOB (binary) or TEXT(has charset support, and might alter some characters)?

Comment: Medium BLOB, perhaps I would use the mysql load_file() instead?

Comment: Are you sure your data gets into the DB correctly? And that it fits in the BLOB fields? Did you tried looking at it with with phpMyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you wouldn't want to have any output code before your http header description. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Either store the filename and other file information in a session then just access them in another page.

A few things that you need to check:

- max_allowed_packet  in my.ini should be equal or higher than the file size that you're expecting to store in the database
- check to see if the data type that you selected fits the file that you will store. There's tiny blob, blog, medium blob and long blob. You might want to try the largest which is long blob.
- I'm not sure about this one but did you already check if file_get_contents works:

`mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($file))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my alternative answer.

First the update query:

Prepare the file (assuming that your file is not a binary file):

```
    $tmpName = $_FILES["pdf_statement"]["tmp_name"];
    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $data = addslashes($data);
    fclose($fp);



$insert="update rd_provider_statement
         set pdf_statement='".$data."', creation_user_id='SCO'
         where  provider_id='".$provider."' and trading_period_month='".$trd_period."'";
```

DOWNLOAD:

```
enter code here

$sql_qry="select provider_id, pdf_statement
          from   rd_provider_statement
          where  provider='".$provider."' 
         and trading_period_month='".$TP_Month."'";

$sql_err_no=sql_select($sql_qry,$sql_res,$sql_row_count,$sql_err,$sql_uerr);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res);
    $name=$row['provider_id'];
    $file=$row['pdf_statement'];


header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\".$name_statement.$TP_format.\";" );
echo $file;
```

Hope it helps =)