# Javascript pass title attribute through function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that gets the value of a select menu and this work great. But i am trying to add another value to the function. So I thought I would use the title attribute for option (please see code below).  The problem is the username parameter in my JavaScript function is `undefined`.

Does anybody have any ideas of what im doing wrong?

**FORM**

```
<form action="">
    <select id="acyear" name="acyear" onchange="showyearlogdays(this.value, this.title)">
    <option value="" label="">- Year -</option>
<?php

$is_business_result = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT(academic_year)FROM holiday_entitlement_business_manual WHERE employee = \'' . $username . '\''); 


    while($acyear_filter = mysql_fetch_array($is_business_result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$acyear_filter['academic_year'].'" title="'.$username.'"';

    $datestr = $acyear_filter['academic_year'];
    $currentyear = substr($datestr, 0, 4);

    if(intval(substr($datestr,4,2)) < 8){$ayear = ($currentyear - 1).'/'.$currentyear;}
    else{$ayear = ($currentyear).'/'.($currentyear + 1);}       
        echo '>';

    echo $ayear;

    echo '</option>';
    }

?>    
    </select>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
   function showyearlogdays(str, username)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","days_yearlog.php?username="+username+"&q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Comment: Using `mysql_query` and concatenating an unquoted string like that is a potential bug and security issue. Please use parameter binding instead.

Comment: @Martijn I think that the OP will find it more helpful if you explain what you are saying.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: Read this page about [protecting MySQL from SQL injection attacks](http://simon.net.nz/articles/protecting-mysql-sql-injection-attacks-using-php/) for more information about SQL injection attacks, and how to protect your code from them. Or see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860130/how-to-bind-sql-variables-in-php).

Comment: @Martijn Thanks! That will be useful, especially for those who do not know very much about mysql like me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `title` attribute of the selected option.  Your code is pointing to the `title` attribute of the `select` tag.  Make the change below:

```
showyearlogdays(this.value, this.options[this.selectedIndex].title)
```

You should also address the security concern mentioned in the comments.  The way your query is setup would make for a really simple SQL Injection attack.  If you don't want to rearchitect it the way the commenter suggested, I would at least escape `$username` so that SQL can't be injected.