# if clauses will not work as wanted

Tags: php

So I have a forum where a user has several characters they can post with. 
Now on the Edit post page I want to have the character that posted the post selected in the select menu.
If the post have been sent and there was an error and the player choose to edit with a another character other than the one that originally made the post I want to have that character selected.

The problem is right now it prints the character that made the post as many times as the users number of characters.

So let's say the character that made this post is called Bob. And the user that owns Bob has 6 characters it will print Bob six times. When it should be Bob selected and then all the other characters. And if they chose to edit with another character I want to have that one selected and then print all the others. I hope you understand.

```
$post = $db->query("SELECT c.subject, a.message, a.hide_smilies, a.posted, b.name, b.user_id, c.id AS topic_id, c.closed, d.id AS forum_id, d.name AS forum_name FROM posts a 
               INNER JOIN characters b ON a.poster = b.id 
               INNER JOIN topics c ON a.topic_id = c.id
               INNER JOIN forums d ON c.forum_id = d.id
               WHERE a.id = $id")->fetch();


Character to edit with:
foreach($db->query("SELECT id, name FROM characters WHERE user_id = $is_logged_in ORDER BY name ASC") as $row):
if (isset($_POST['character']) && ($row['id'] == $_POST['character'])) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" selected>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
} else if (isset($post['name'])) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" selected>'.$post['name'].'</option>';
} else  {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
endforeach
```

Comment: Your query is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen. Please use bind variables, and save yourself and your users headaches in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860130/how-to-bind-sql-variables-in-php

Comment: Please learn how to use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: Do all of the user's characters have the same `characters.id`?

Comment: @Palpatim $id = isset($_GET['postid']) ? intval($_GET['postid']) : 0;

Comment: @Barmar Every character has an unique ID. in The posts table it's stored in 'poster'.

Comment: Which query are you having a problem with? The one used to assign to `$post` or the one in the `foreach`?

Comment: The problem is here: `if (isset($post['name'])) {` will be true every time through the loop. So it will keep printing `$post['name']`. I can't figure out what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a complete answer but it is a start* it's too big to fit in a comment!

Using bound variables to prevent SQL injections (as suggested by others in comments). Improve loop structure and other improvements

```php
$sql = <<<EOF
SELECT c.subject, a.message, a.hide_smilies, a.posted, b.name, b.user_id, c.id AS topic_id, c.closed, d.id AS forum_id, d.name AS forum_name 
FROM posts a 
INNER JOIN characters b ON a.poster = b.id 
INNER JOIN topics c ON a.topic_id = c.id
INNER JOIN forums d ON c.forum_id = d.id
WHERE a.id = ?
EOF;

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("s", $is_logged_in); 
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

```php
$char_sql = <<<EOF
SELECT id, name 
FROM characters WHERE user_id = ? 
ORDER BY name ASC
EOF;

$stmt = $db->prepare($char_sql);
$stmt->bind_param( "s", $id);
$result = $stmt->execute();


foreach ($result->fetch_row($char_sql) as $row):
    $id = $row['id']; $name = $row['name'];
    if (isset($_POST['character']) && ($id == $_POST['character'])) {
       echo "<option value='{$id}' selected>{$name}</option>";
    } else if (isset($post['name'])) {
        echo "<option value='{$id}' selected>{$post['name']}</option>";
    } else  {
        echo "<option value='{$id}'>{$name}</option>";
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: This is a good recommendation, but how will it solve the problem he's having? It should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I haven't finished yet!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
} else if (isset($post['name'])) {
```

to:

```
} else if ($post && $post['name'] == $row['name']) {
```

`isset($post['name']` is the same every time through the loop, , so you were printing `$post['name']` for each row fetched.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what is needed as it effectively makes the first two if conditions print the same option statement

Comment: But he's using `else if`, so only one of them will be used. I don't know the relationship between `$_POST['character']` and `$post['name']`.