# How to bind variables while connecting to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'testdb1';
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname='.$dbname, $username, $password);
```

How to bind all the variables in this connection command so that I can prevent MySQL injection? Because when I connect to my db like this:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb1', 'root', '');
```

Everything is fine and all columns are getting updated properly. But when I use variables in my connection, either I don't get some fields (particularly `password` column) or I am unable to INSERT to some columns.

please help me!

Comment: Can you post reproducible code related to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Mind your words Bro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind SQL variables in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860130/how-to-bind-sql-variables-in-php)