# bindParam works correctly no matter what data type is specified or given

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

While introducing myself to pgSQL prepared statements, I've successfully returned the results of a few queries. However, I have a few questions.

Given the following query:

```
$w_ft = "36"; 
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM main_products_common_dimensions WHERE w_ft = :w_ft");
$sth->bindParam(':w_ft', $theId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

I notice that even though the column in the `main_products_common_dimensions` table is a `character_varying`, I get the same/correct result set returned if I use

```
$w_ft = 36; 
...
$sth->bindParam(':w_ft', $w_ft, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

and

```
$w_ft = "36"; 
...
$sth->bindParam(':w_ft', $w_ft, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

and

```
$w_ft = "36"; 
...
$sth->bindParam(':w_ft', $w_ft, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

and

```
$w_ft = 36; 
...
$sth->bindParam(':w_ft', $w_ft, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

That is, no matter how I bind the parameter `_INT` or `_STR` or set the variable (integer or string), the data is returned correctly. Is this normal behavior?

From http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php, I see that the parameter datatype is explained

> Explicit data type for the parameter using the PDO::PARAM_* constants.
>   To return an INOUT parameter from a stored procedure, use the bitwise
>   OR operator to set the PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT bits for the data_type
>   parameter.

What is meant by "returning an INOUT parameter from a stored procedure"? Is this related? Does that imply that I am not using a stored procedure? Length seems to be optional, though that is not indicated in its explanation. Are there advantages to providing it?

As you can see, I'm quite new to this, and just trying to get my head around it. Thank you very much

Comment: shouldn't `$theId` be `$w_ft` in your `$sth->bindParam....`?

Comment: @Tikkes aha, yes, I changed that at the last minute, but missed in the bindparam. fixing... Thank you!

Comment: @Tikkes Ah, no I'm sorry. I didn't make myself clear. I have this correct in the actual code I'm using. And the problem is not that it _does not_ work, but rather that the (now corrected and accurate) code _does_ work. Thanks the same

Comment: So the code you have above now does work? or doesn't it? I'm a bit confused now

Comment: @Tikkes It does. But this seems to be an exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833510/php-pdobindparam-data-types-how-does-it-work) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes I was looking at it too, misread your question at first. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: The behavior was considered a bug and was fixed in [php 8](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PDO::PARAM_STR` when passed to `bindParam()` are indications that the driver is free to ignore.

Looking at PDO pg driver's [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_pgsql/pgsql_driver.c), it appears that, except for `PDO_PARAM_LOB` which is treated specially, all types are quoted as strings (that is, between quotes and passed to libpq's `PQescapeStringConn` function)

You should also be aware of the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` attribute that controls what method is used under the hood. When `false`, `PQprepare()` is used with real out-of-query parameters. If `true`, parameter values are injected into the SQL passed to the non-parametrized `PQexec()`.
Technically, this is quite different, so you may see differing behaviors in corner cases or error cases depending on this attribute.

Comment: This was [fixed in php 8](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$w_ft = 36; 
...
$sth->bindParam(':w_ft', $theId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

should be

```
$w_ft = 36; 
...
$sth->bindParam(':w_ft', $w_ft, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `postgres` accepts the quoting of integers when comparing with an integer column.

So if your id column is an int, these queries both work the same:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '1';
```

What the `PDO::PARAM_*` constants do is modify the way the quoting/escaping is done to the values, and is independent of the value datatype. Php also will make a type conversion if needed. If you choose `PDO::PARAM_INT` you are telling the DBMS driver that the value of $id is an integer, and should escape it as an integer, so it will not add quotes around it when it puts the value into the query.

```
$id = 1;
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = :id");
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// resulting query would be SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;

$sometext = "hello";
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = :id");
$sth->bindParam(':id', $sometext, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// in this case, $sometext will be casted to an integer, that will result in (int)0
// resulting query would be SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 0;

$sometext = "hello";
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = :id");
$sth->bindParam(':id', $sometext, PDO::PARAM_STR);
// in this case, $sometext is already a string, and strings should be quoted
// resulting query would be SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 'hello';
```

Also, about the INOUT param of `bindParam`, if you aren't going to use INOUT or OUT parameters of a stored procedure (like, say, passing a reference to a function call than is setted inside the function), you probably are better using [`bindValue`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindValue). Using `bindValue` you can put the result of a function or any constant value as the value to bind, you don't need to put a variable.

```
$sth->bindValue(':something', 5);
$sth->bindValue(':something_else', $foo->bar());
```