# PDO inserting specific data type

Tags: php, pdo

Help me please.
I insered into varchar column

```
$nul='mystring';
$STH->bindParam(':param',$nul , PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

If **PDO :: PARAM_INT** mean to go into the database insert number **(int) $ nul = 0**! there is a record string 'mystring'. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [PHP PDO::bindParam() data types.. how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833510/php-pdobindparam-data-types-how-does-it-work)

PDO::PARAM_INT only converts booleans to integers. Nothing else.

If you want to convert the string to an int use intval

Comment: Or simply cast it: `$STH->bindParam(':param', (int)$nul, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: True you can also cast it. And technically a cast is faster.

Comment: @h2ooooooo this particular line of code would cause an error.

Comment: @YourCommonSense because bind param wants a reference, so you have to stick the cast in a variable first? That's going to give a warning... Am I missing the error?

Comment: @YourCommonSense You're completely right - I missed the fact that it was `bindParam` and not `bindValue`.

Comment: That's why I always prefer bindValue

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you want the value to be null (indeterminate value) in the database, but in practice you're getting the string 'nul'.

If you are setting something to null, it doesn't need the apostrophes.

```
// Setting the value of the string
$string_to_insert = 'my_string';

// Checks that the string has a value, if not sets to NULL
$value = isset($string_to_insert) ?  $string_to_insert : null;

// Bind the parameter
$STH->bindParam(':param', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

If you put apostrophes around it, you will receive that literal string in your database.

NULL is a constant, check out the docs here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: I'm sorry I brought not a good example. I would like to say any string , not null.  Thank you very much for your example

Comment: I've changed it so that it checks there is a value to insert, if not it sets it to null.  Does this answer the question?