# PDO::PARAM_STR and PDO::PARAM_INT not giving error

Tags: php, oop

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO test(name,city)VALUES(:vary,'china')");
$sql->bindParam('vary',$vary, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$vary=1234;
$sql->execute();
```

This should give error because i am not using string, for `:vary` parameter . but this is working fine  and insert a row in table `test`. can someone explain why there is no error, i find same question on stackoverflow [PHP PDO::bindParam() data types.. how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833510/php-pdobindparam-data-types-how-does-it-work)  But i am still confused, can someone PLEASE explain better..

Comment: *"not giving error"* - are you checking for them? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- IT inserts a row in table,so it is working fine

Comment: What is the column's type? If it's varchar then it won't throw an error since `$vary` doesn't contain a string character. If your column were an `int`, then that would be a different story.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I change the column type to to int, still working fine

Comment: I think their is no use of  PDO::PARAM_INT

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't give you any errors because of PHP's type juggling. In other words: PHP silently casts the integer `1234` into the string `1234`, when you try to use it as a string.

Read more about the [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in the PHP manual.