# PDO query binding string instead of integer returns results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table with and auto increment id and was just testing a few scenarios when I stumbled across a problem whereby PDO or mysql seems to convert a string to an integer when in an array.  Does anyone know why?

If my query is as follows:

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE id=:id");
$check->execute(array(':id'=>1));
```

it retrieves 1 record - all fine, but if the query uses a string either by design or mistake as follows:

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE id=:id");
$check->execute(array(':id'=>'1 OR id > 0'));
```

it still retrieves a record with id=1.

Surely nothing should be found?  I appreciate I should never allow the 2nd scenario to happen but why is PDO / mysql converting the string to an integer and how is it doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a MySQL bug/oversight in string to integer conversion. Instead of raising an error when given an incorrect integer literal, it simply issues a warning.

```
mysql> select '1'+0;
+-------+
| '1'+0 |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select '1 hello world'+0;
+-------------------+
| '1 hello world'+0 |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                           |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1 hello world' |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Interestingly even if I bind a parameter and use 'PDO::PARAM_INT' it makes no difference - just issues a warning.

Comment: I was quite surprised to find `bindParam` doesn't throw an Exception when you attempt to bind a string with `PDO::PARAM_INT` as well... seems it follows PHPs general String > Int conversion rules.

Comment: ... actually `bindParam` doesn't even do what I thought: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833510/php-pdobindparam-data-types-how-does-it-work (did some further digging and deleted my incorrect answer when it was pointed out) @user2875878

Comment: Weeelll... it's PHP. Anyone expecting PHP to do the right thing with types is on drugs...

Comment: @peufeu However, in this precise situation it behaves exactly as MySQL does ([demo](https://3v4l.org/1YseC)) and it isn't more insane than JavaScript ([demo](http://jsbin.com/yoyukadexe/1/edit?js,console)).

Answer (score 3):

For good or bad, that's how MySQL is designed to behave:

```
mysql> SELECT CASE
    -> WHEN 123='123 pink elephants' THEN 'Equal'
    -> ELSE 'Different' END
    -> AS 'How are they?';
+---------------+
| How are they? |
+---------------+
| Equal         |
+---------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, though, it triggers a warning:

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '123 pink elephants' |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `execute` create somthing like: `SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE id='1 OR id > 0'`

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE id=:id OR id>:id2");
$check->execute(array(':id'=>'1', ':id2' => 0));
```

or just

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE id>:id");
$check->execute(array(':id'=>'0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

With prepared statements and placeholders, the database knows to expect a value that suits the column type.  I would expect that it sees your numeric id column and casts the '1 or id > 0' to a number - so you just get the 1.